# How to make inherited abstract method from parent abstract for own children?

Tags: c#

I want to pass abstraction of a method down from the first parent to the children of the children of that parent.
The body of this method is empty but I want to force both the children of this class and the children of the children class to implement exactly this method.

I've tried finding similar questions but have failed. This might be due to me not understanding the use of "abstract" correctly. In this case, I apologise.

Here is an example in code:

```
    public abstract class A
    {
        public abstract void ImportantMethod();
    }

    public abstract class B : A
    {
        public override void ImportantMethod()
        {
            // now this method will still not be used but MUST be implemented in child classes of this class
        }
    }

    public class C : B
    {
        // I can override this method, but it is not enforced - and that is what I am after.
        public override void ImportantMethod()
        {

        }
    }
```

It is obviously possible that I am using abstraction the wrong way and that there is a specific way to do this, but I would like to know what that is and why as I am a new programmer.

Comment: Don't override the method in class B, then. This will leave the method being abstract (which is okay, because B itself is an abstract class, thus it can possess abstract methods), and forces any concrete class inheriting from B (such as class C) to implement this abstract method...

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word `abstract` means that at least one of the inheriting classes must implement this method.

- If B does implement it, you have no way to force C to do so.
- If B does not implement it, B must be declared abstract and the implementation will be left to B inheritors.